# Python code for PSO to optimise SVM parameters

Tags: python, svm, particle-swarm

I'm trying to implement Particle swarm optimization on support vector machine (SVM) to optimizing cost and gamma parameters (Radial basis function) to improve the accuracy.The SVM program is taking data from mysql db and is working fine.Now I need a PSO code to optimize the cost and gamma parameters and use it in svm program.
following are the svm and pso codes. Svm works fine but the PSO code does not work.
the code is written in python.
Please help..

SVM code:

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi
import cgitb
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm 
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd
cgitb.enable()
print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
e1= form.getvalue('EARNING_PER_SHARE', '')
e2 = form.getvalue('CASH_INVESTMENT', '')
e3 = form.getvalue('CURRENT_LIABILITY', '')
e4 = form.getvalue('TOTAL_REVENUE', '')
e5 = form.getvalue('GROSS_PROFIT', '')
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", db="cisco", user="root", passwd="")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO table1 (EARNING_PER_SHARE, CASH_INVESTMENT, CURRENT_LIABILITY, 
TOTAL_REVENUE,GROSS_PROFIT) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
""", (e1, e2, e3, e4,e5))
db.commit()
db.close()
db_connection = sql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='cisco', user='root', 
password='')
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table1')
table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
np = df.as_matrix()
X = df.drop([4], 1)
np1 = X.as_matrix()
y = df[4]
np2 = y.as_matrix()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np1, np2, test_size=0.3)
clf = svm.SVR()
clf.fit(np1, np2)
confidence = clf.score(np1, np2)
for k in ['rbf']:
clf = svm.SVR(kernel=k, C=100, gamma=0.0001)
clf.fit(np1, np2)
confidence = clf.score(np1, np2)
print(k,confidence)
a = clf.predict(np1)
print ('\npredicted values')
print (a)
print ('\nreal values')
print (np2)
```

PSO code:

```
def fitness_function(a,x,np2,np1,C,gamma,):    
C = x[0]
gamma = x[1]
clf = svm.SVR(kernel=k, C=10, gamma=0.0001,swarmsize=50)
clf.fit(np1, np2)
confidence = clf.score(np1, np2)
print(k,confidence)
mse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(np2, a))
return mse
lb = [10, 0.0001]
ub = [1000,0.1]
xopt, fopt = pso(fitness_function, lb, ub)
```

I want to use RMSE as the fitness function but I think fitness function has to include the parameters that is to be optimized. But, in SVR, the objective function is too complicated to write in python.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: the PSO code is not working.I want to use RMSE as the fitness function and get the optimised value of cost and gamma.5-fold cross-validation can also be used to estimate the RMSE for a given set of parameters.